# Apache mod_rewrite and php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a slight of problem. 
I used simple php framework on github and have worked on it and added new functions and so on.

The framework that i have had help with is this:
https://github.com/panique/mini

Everything works perfectly in a MAMP environment, but now when i was going to test it on a live website and apache environment it does not work that good.
It obviously can read the index file since i point the directory to the directory that should be used for apache.

But when i am going to make a call to a controller (domain.com/login) it results in apache giving me :

"Not Found: The requested URL /login was not found on this server."

I have enabled rewrite with: service a2enmod rewrite, and i double checked and it is a Loaded module when looking in phpinfo().

The .htaccess file that is located in the  "/var/www/html/php-project/public" directory(where i have pointed to in my virtual host file"
is the following:

```
# Necessary to prevent problems when using a controller named "index" and having a root index.php
Options -MultiViews

# Activates URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Prevent people from looking directly into folders
Options -Indexes

# If the following conditions are true, then rewrite the URL:
# If the requested filename is not a directory,

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# and if the requested filename is not a regular file that exists,
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and if the requested filename is not a symbolic link,
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
# then rewrite the URL in the following way:
# Take the whole request filename and provide it as the value of a
# "url" query parameter to index.php. Append any query string from
# the original URL as further query parameters (QSA), and stop
# processing this .htaccess file (L).
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

00-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        ServerName www.domain.com
        ServerAlias domain.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/php-project/public
        <Directory />
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        #DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

apache.conf

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

#<Directory /srv/>
#       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#       AllowOverride None
#       Require all granted
#</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess
```

I dont think the problem is within the php itself.
Thats why i don't added my code since its so many classes, but the code is as i said based on the framework in the beginning of the question.

Do any of you see any obvious problems in the conf's?
I have searched and searched for answers, but i don't seem to get it right. So i would really really appreciate some help. 
Any questions, just ask on.
Thanks

Comment: This simplest way to determine if `.htaccess` is even honoured is to make a syntax error on purpose. If you get 500 Server Error then everything works from Apache point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the proper way of access rewrite module in apache2.

First enable the rewrite module in apache using below command-:

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Open the apache2.conf file

```
$ nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Update the  section

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Remove the section   from 00-default.conf 
Remove the below lines

```
         <Directory />
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
```

Then finally restart your apache2.

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

or

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```